# How to implement loops in tensorflow

Tags: loops, tensorflow

I am learning tesnsorflow currently. it is possible to implement such a code in tensorflow when eager execution is not enabled ?.

```
for param, dparam, mem in zip([self.W1,self.W2,self.W3,self.W4,self.W5,self.b1,self.b2,self.b3,self.b4,self.b5],[dW1,dW2,dW3,dW4,dW5,db1,db2,db3,db4,db5],[mW1,mW2,mW3,mW4,mWO,mb1,mb2,mb3,mb4,mbO]):
                        mem += dparam * dparam
                        param += -(self.learning_rate * dparam/(np.sqrt(mem+1e-8)))
```

Comment: You can try [`tf.map_fn()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) and [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop). But I recommend that you try not to use tensorflow loop function as much as possible since them will affect computing performance.

Answer (score 0):

Tensor objects are not iterable. So, to answer your question, there is no zip-like function in TensorFlow.

You can indeed use `tf.map_fn` to apply a function to a sequence of tensors.

Your can use following sample program for that,

```
# declare variables 
dparam  = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4])

# NOTE: use stack because map_tf only takes one input tensor
ab = tf.stack([dparam , dparam ], 1)


def map_operation(value_dparam ):
    # iterates each value_dparam 
    value_a = value_dparam [0]
    value_b = value_dparam [1]
    return value_a*value_b

# iterates each value_ab at map_operation()
map_result = tf.map_fn(map_operation, dparam , dtype=tf.int32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    print(sess.run(map_result))         # [1*1 2*2 3*3 4*4]

''' output
[1 4 9 16]
'''
```